# Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

How can I fix the error `Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory - /app/tmp/sitemaps`? I have the file: tmp/sitemaps/sitemap.xml.gz.

```
$ heroku run rake sitemap:upload_to_s3
Running rake sitemap:upload_to_s3 on livetochallenge.... up, run.2043
Starting sitemap upload to S3...
rake aborted!
Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory - /app/tmp/sitemaps
```

This is lib/tasks/sitemap.rake:

```
# Code Based Upon Comment Made In Below Tutorial Unless Specified Here
namespace :sitemap do
  desc 'Upload the sitemap files to S3'
  task upload_to_s3: :environment do
    puts 'Starting sitemap upload to S3...'
    s3 = Aws::S3::Resource.new
    bucket = s3.bucket(ENV['AWS_BUCKET']) # I refer to it as AWS not S3. I couldn't figure out the latter and not sure if it makes a difference. In production.rb paperclip_defaults I set it :bucket => ENV['AWS_BUCKET']
    Dir.entries(File.join(Rails.root, 'tmp', 'sitemaps')).each do |file_name|
      next if %w(. .. .DS_Store).include? file_name
      path = "sitemaps/#{file_name}"
      file = File.join(Rails.root, 'tmp', 'sitemaps', file_name)
      object = bucket.object(path)
      object.upload_file(file)
      puts "Saved #{file_name} to S3"
    end
  end
```

config/sitemap.rb:

```
SitemapGenerator::Sitemap.default_host = 'http://www.livetochallenge.com/'
SitemapGenerator::Sitemap.public_path = 'tmp/sitemaps/'

SitemapGenerator::Sitemap.create do
  add challenges_path, changefreq: 'daily'
  Challenge.find_each do |f|
    add challenge_path(f), lastmod: f.updated_at
  end
end

SitemapGenerator::Sitemap.ping_search_engines
```

routes.rb

```
get '/sitemap.xml.gz', to: redirect("https://#{ENV['AWS_BUCKET']}.s3.amazonaws.com/sitemaps/sitemap.xml.gz"), as: :sitemap
```

I'm using AWS SDK v2.2.31.

[image]

I followed tutorial, [Creating a sitemap with Ruby on Rails and uploading it to Amazon S3](http://cookieshq.co.uk/posts/creating-a-sitemap-with-ruby-on-rails-and-upload-it-to-amazon-s3/).

Comment: is the file part of source control?

Comment: Nothing to do with S3... `File.join(Rails.root, 'tmp', 'sitemaps')` seems to indicate that `Rails.root` is evaluating as "/app" -- so you should probably fix that and the rest will fall into place.

Comment: Just tested @Michael-sqlbot. Error remains. Maybe I did it work. I put `File.join('/app', 'tmp', 'sitemaps')`

Comment: That's sort of the opposite of what I intended.  Your app apparently is not in `/app` -- it's somewhere else, so you need the correct directory there, **not** `/app` -- which is why you're getting the error.

Comment: Ah you're right. It is under LiveToChallenge. I took a pic because I still got error `Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory - LiveToChallenge/tmp/sitemaps`. You mind providing an answer with how I should write it @Michael-sqlbot?

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot it is weird because I could cd to it: `MacBook-Pro:livetochallenge $ cd ~/dropbox/LiveToChallenge/tmp/sitemaps
MacBook-Pro:sitemaps $`

Comment: Should I not be running it as `heroku run rake sitemap:upload_to_s3` and just do `rake sitemap:upload_to_s3` @Michael-sqlbot? I want the sitemap to work for production though. If I do the latter I get a different error: `Aws::Errors::MissingRegionError: missing region; use :region option or export region name to ENV['AWS_REGION']`